# Selenium click on button trouble (Python web scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to web scraping a popular movie database on the Internet. After a few thousands of requests, my spider is detected and I have to manually click on a simple button to continue my data collection.

I have tried to automatize this process by clicking automatically in that button. For that purpose, I am using Selenium library. I have located the xpath of the button, but, for some reason, *.click()* method doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
def click_button():
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
    DRIVER_PATH = 'geckodriver'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    driver.get('https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/main.html')
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Send']")
    element.click()
    driver.quit()
```

Also, I have tried other common alternatives, such as waiting until the element gets clickable or visible, but this didn't work. I have also tried to execute the click as a javascript script.

This is the window I see when my spider is detected:

[Too many request window (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7kt4.png)

As you see, there is a reCaptcha-protection icon on the lower right corner, but I don't have to solve any captcha puzzle to confirm I am not a robot, I have just to click on the *send* button you can see on the picture.

The html which contains the button is the following one:

```
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Too many requests</h1>
            
            <div class="image">
                <img height="400" src="/images/too-many-request.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                Are you sure you do not dream of electric sheep?
            </div>
            <form name="toomanyrequest">
                <div class="alert">
                    please enter the Captcha to continue.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Which do you think is the trouble with my code or approach? I have to find a way to click on that button to continue my scraping, but I don't know what I am doing wrong (I have little experience at this field).

Maybe the xpath is not correct? Maybe the captcha protection is blocking the click action? I don't get any exception when I execute my code; but nothing happens and the "Too many request" window does not disappear.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure how can one replicate this issue. However, if you've this `<input type="submit" value="Send">` then this xpath `//input[@value='Send']` is correct. However, this could be in an iframe, or in a shadow root.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anwer. How could I know if it is in an iframe and what should I do in that case (same with shadow root).

Comment: Can you share image snippet of html with iframe ? Let's be clear on iframe or shadow root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

or:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```